# Permissions Hosting .NET Core out-of-process with files on a network drive

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2, windows-server-2016, iis-10, kestrel-http-server

I have a new .NET Core API which is targeting full .Net framework so is being hosted out of process in IIS. This is working fine locally in Visual Studio, also good in a test environment using IIS, however deploying to production this is not working. The difference I can see is the test environment has a local drive with the API files, and production API files are set with a UNC path in IIS, the App Pool runs as a domain user that has full access to the network folder. The API fails to launch with errors which messages are shown below from the event log, including failing to write to logs stdout. However if I set the App Pool to run as a domain admin account, all is well and the API runs. I can't run as this user though of course, so my question is what permissions or trust levels am I missing here. I am new to .NET Core, so I am unsure what extra permissions may be required. Other full .NET Framework websites and services are running okay on this server with their files on this network drive.

Here are the event log messages when running the App Pool as the non-admin domain user.

Application EventLog for Source: "IIS AspNetCore Module V2" Warning: "Could not create stdoutLogFile \?\UNC\fileclstr\Websites\WebsiteName\API\logs\stdout_20191205204322_15236.log, ErrorCode = '0x800700a1'."

Application EventLog for Source: .NET Runtime Error: "Application: DistributedServices.WebsiteName.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Sockets.SocketTransport.BindAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer+<>c__DisplayClass21_0`1+<<StartAsync>g__OnBind|0>d[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication+Context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder+<BindEndpointAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.ListenOptions+<BindAsync>d__43.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder+AddressesStrategy+<BindAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder+<BindAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer+<StartAsync>d__21`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.HostingApplication+Context, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost+d__26.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions+d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions+d__4.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(System.Threading.Tasks.Task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHost)
   at DistributedServices.WebsiteName.Program.Main(System.String[])"

Application Eventlog for Source: "Application Error" Error: "Faulting application name: DistributedServices.WebsiteName.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0xf4041a68
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.14393.3321, time stamp: 0x5da7e8d8
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000dc232
Faulting process ID: 0x2bf8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d5abaca2aaaf51
Faulting application path: \fileclstr\Websites\WebsiteName\API\DistributedServices.WebsiteName.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report ID: c68c4bdd-e46d-4628-8be3-63b1f6cc78dc
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID: "

Application EventLog Source: "IIS AspNetCore Module V2" Warning: "Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/api' with physical root '\fileclstr\Websites\WebsiteName\API\' failed to start process with commandline '\fileclstr\Websites\WebsiteName\API\DistributedServices.WebsiteName.exe ' at stage 'PostStartCheck', ErrorCode = '0x8027025b', assigned port 38520, retryCounter '1'."

Here is the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore" />
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" existingResponse="PassThrough">
      <clear />
    </httpErrors>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\DistributedServices.WebSiteName.exe" arguments="" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"  />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Asp.net Core 2.2, kestrel out of process, IIS10, Windows Server 2016.

Comment: I suggest you to follow best practices and not trying to fix issues because of strange approach. Build, release, deploy. Don't serve application from network share.

Comment: “The API fails to launch with socket exceptions thrown”, edit your question to include the actual exception please. "fails to write to logs stdout", what does Process Monitor say about the file access?

Comment: Hi Vladimir, my description may not have been clear. But we are using Azure DevOps pipelines for build and deployment. We just have application reasons why we use shared storage. What I'd like to focus on here is how Core out of process works with permissions, and why the API runs okay with my admin account and not with the non-admin account running the app pool. Thank you.

Comment: Lex Li, thank you for your feedback. I have updated to include the event log errors and warnings now.

Comment: I have updated the web.config to output to a folder on C drive and this has created logs, showing on start-up it is failing with the socket exception but it is trying to connect to SQL Server and failing. The SQL Server uses integrated security, connecting as the user running the app so I think this is the issue, along with the logs not being created on the share. I think the out of proc app is not running as my App Pool identity, any ideas how I can control the user it runs as? Is the App Pool identity the way for out of process? Thank you.

Comment: When you need to troubleshooting NTFS permission issue, it is recommended to begin with Microsoft Process monitor https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon. It will tell you where is access denied or access violation thrown and what application identity are used for this operation.

Answer (score 1):

This has taken many days, but I've finally got there.

The user had permissions on \\fileclstr\Websites\WebsiteName\ but this seemingly was not enough, and giving permissions to \\fileclstr\Websites\ allowed this to run in IIS out-of-process mode .NET Core targeting the full framework.

Thank you for your comments.